# X windowで自作サイトのJavascriptが実行できません

Tags: javascript, php, apache, raspberry-pi

原因を特定できず、このカテゴリで質問させていただきます。
Raspberry pi-Debian-apache2-PHP5の環境でサイトを作成しました。
Windows PCのブラウザからは問題なく動作できたのですが、
linux のX WindowのブラウザからだとJavaScriptが全く動作しません。
alertを出すだけのサンプルでテストしても動きませんでした。
X Windowで自作ローカルサイトをアクセス　JS動かず
別のRasPiからX Windowで自作サイトをリモートアクセス　JS動かず
でした。yahoo等の他サイトは問題なく動きます。
何か設定に漏れがあるのでしょうか。ご教授お願い致します。

Comment: "X Window"は"GUI環境"ということを言いたいのだと思いますが、できれば具体的なブラウザの種類やバージョン、実際のコードなども提示してもらわないと回答は難しいと思います。

Comment: 参考までに、webサーバ経由(`http://`)ではなくローカルのファイル(`file://`)として開いていると、JavaScriptの実行がブラウザでブロックされている場合があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ブラウザはepiphanyです。http://IPアドレス(192.168.～）/index.phpで開いています。